# page numbers in bibliography not correctly printed if list contains {pp. 12-34} in bib file

Tags: biblatex

I am having trouble with the print of my bibliography.

I have a bib file which looks like this

```
    @Article{Sample:01,
  Title                    = {Some Title},
  Author                   = {Doe, John},
  Year                     = {111},
  Pages                    = {pp. 1-2},
  Journal                  = {Really Cool Journal},
  }

    @Article{Sample:02,
  Title                    = {Different Title},
  Author                   = {Doe, Jane},
  Year                     = {222},
  Pages                    = {3-4},
  Journal                  = {Other Cool Journal},
  }
```

I use this with `biblatex` and `biber`.

However my bibliography is printed correctly for the 2nd type but not for the first (i.e. *pages 3-4*), whereas in the second case it only says *pages*.

I get this non-unified style of the page list, since I collect the citations from different internet sources, that sometimes have the first sometimes the second type.

Is there anyway I could tell biber to ignore any *pp.* in the list **Pages** and always print out *pages a-b*?

My workaround so far is to change the lists by hand and remove the *pp.* However, I feel there must be some way to do that automatically.

So far I was unable to find one. Has anybody an idea about this?

For the record: I am using MikTex 2,9 and compile using `pdflatex` invoked via the `latexmk` package.

Here is a minimal working example that creates the error with the above bib file stored as mybib in the same folder.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, natbib
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
    \citet{Sample:01}, \citet{Sample:02}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and congrats for this beautiful (almost) [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I reduced it a bit further to eliminate unneeded package and documentclass options.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I should have tried whether it had worked that way. Sorry, for the unecessary mess...

Comment: No problem, your code was pretty fine and far from being a "mess". We have seen much bigger and messier code given as "MWE" by much more experienced users here.

Comment: Looks a bug in `biber`. You can put text there that isn't pagenumbers, like "Chapter 3" or "First appendix". My guess is code that looks for "pp." especially to handle those entries as normal digit-starting entries, but then there is some error.

A workaround is therefore to use `backend=bibtex` if you don't need `biber`features. (But of course we all need `biber`features! :-)

Comment: As you said, we all need biber features. So thanks for the suggestion, but `bibtex` would cut down the features to a set I wouldn't want

Comment: I've reported as bug at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/25 .

Comment: You shouldn't write `pp.` inside the bib file. It's the job of `biblatex` to print automatically `pp.`.

Comment: @ppr this is probably true. However, e.g. Jstor does it when you export a citation

Comment: @johaschn I understand. By the way, `\citet` is working only for natbib compatibility. If you use only biblatex you should prefer using other cite related commands (see biblatex manual p.88)

Comment: @ppr Ok. Well so far I always had natbib=true as an option and used my old (pre-biblatex) style of citing. But, yeah, I'll change that then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask biber to do such replacements for you. My facility with regular expressions is patchy at best, but I think this works:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pages,
            match=\regexp{pp\.(.+)},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright. That really does the job. However, now I have some problem with my text editor (Sublime Text2&LaTexTools) that thinks I am in inline math mode all the time and the syntax highlighting is screwed. I am not so firm in regular expressions to have an equivalent phrase at hand. Is there some, you think?

Comment: I'd generalise (for spacing after the "pp", and to deal with just "p" for single pages) a little `match=\regexp{pp?\.?\ ?(.+)}`

Comment: Add a comment " % $" after the line with $. Maybe put ending "]" on the next line too, to make it easier for the editor.

Comment: ... but I'm always wary of matching too much with `.+` and would prefer `[0-9\-\ ]+` (might not need the first backslash, I can't remember when you need to escape the hyphen/minus.

Comment: @Chris H Thanks. That looks much more confusing so I'm sure it's better! Feel free to edit that in to the answer, or not, as you wish.

Comment: @PaulStanley - only if I get a chance to test it!

Comment: @ChrisH I'm afraid something seems wrong in your regexp. There it does not do what it is supposed to (in fact it does nothing). As said. No real clue about regexp, thus cannot spot the bug

Comment: About the text highlighting: I found another (dirty) workaround for that. I store the DeclareSourcemap in another file and load it with `\input`, that way syntax highlighting is not affected. For me this does the job since I have some packages I always load anyway stored in a separate folder (on my svn) that is included in all projects. If this wasn't the case, this workaround might of course not work. `% $`did not work unfortunately

Comment: So have you really tested this? I'm surprised, because I was writing essentially the same thing, but didn't get it to work, thinking it was because the buggy change biber did came before we got a chance to change the fields ourselves.

Comment: @pst you mean me? I have tested Chris H's solution as well as PaulStanleys. The latter worked the former not...

Comment: @johaschn, OK, thanks, good to hear. I don't understand what's up for me, but that will have to wait.

Comment: OK, so here I'm just testing the regexp, not via biber (I don't want to break anything right now). new match:`pages\ ?=\ ?\{pp?\.?\ ?(.+)\}` new replace:`pages = \{$1\}` - does biber handle the escaped `{`s OK?.  This will pass anything like `pages={1 \emph{et seq.}} in case you want that.  My previous broke because too much was optional and it was matching the "p" at the beginning of "page", then skipping some optional stuff before the ".+" matched the rest of the line.  When using regexps with biber I like to match the "key=" bit as well to reduce unintended consequences.

Comment: I'm not sure what the escaped \{\} are doing: by the time biber does these replacements its already looking at the data within bibtex braces, so you don't need to duplicate those

Comment: @Chris H Somehow biber seems not too like too many options. It does do ok on single pages with `p.` but seems to not change anything once its `pp.` with your code

Comment: In addition I found at least a solution to `p.` and `pp.`with the match `p{1,2}\.(.+)`

Comment: @PaulStanley, of course, biber works on the contents of a known field so you don't need to do all the `page\ ?=\ ?\{` nonsense I did.

Comment: @johaschn - that should help, my previous comment address to Paul Stanley explains some of the mistake I made while being wary of breaking stuff with biber.

Comment: @ChrisH: `match=\regexp{pp?\.?(.+)}` works fine, and deals with entries starting with p, pp, p., or pp. correctly. It just doesn't like the space. You should NOT replace `(.+)` with `[0-9\-\ ]+` or similar: page numbers can look all sorts of ways!

Comment: @Kundor I've been caught out by `(.+)` type matches catching surprising things before before so I'm slightly wary.  `[0-9\-\ ]+` catches all the page number field contents in my master .bib, but I've already dealt with those that use various dashes, unicode hyphens, "to" etc.

Comment: It's only applied to the pages field, so you want to be sure not to leave anything out (except the initial pp.) So you are going the wrong direction: you need to be careful not to omit anything. There could be roman numerals, appended letters, infinite cardinals, who knows what.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all the '{pp. ' with '{ ' using Replace option of any text editor!

Comment: As the OP already wrote "My workaround so far is to change the lists by hand and remove the pp.", so he's aware of that, but he's asking for a solution directly in `biber` or `biblatex` so that there's no need to take care if there's a "pp." in the pages field or not.

Comment: I doubt that there is something automatic that is been implemented in bibtex for this specific task. However, one can write a small 'sed' code to take care of this problem.

Comment: @sina, This is not about bibtex but about biber, and it does indeed do something automatic, otherwise it would just have copied the value (as it does if you write for example "Chapter Two" as value).